# Как запретить ввод цифр в поле (jqueryvalidate)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

сейчас поле просто обязательное

```js
  $("form").validate({
 
  });
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" required>
  <button>btn</button>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Судя по списку методов валидации [List of built-in Validation methods](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#link-list-of-built-in-validation-methods) такого метода там нет. Если желаете использовать jQuery Validate, то Вам нужно будет добавить соответствующий метод самостоятельно. Либо в данном случае можно обойтись и без jQuery Validate, так как в любом случае Вам нужно будет добавлять эту валидацию самой.

Comment: @Simon. а как добавить метод ? я понимаю что нужно использовать \w+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил пример. Используя [jQuery.validator.addMethod()](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) добавляем свой метод валидации, я назвал его `symbols`, добавляем туда регулярное выражение при помощи которого проверяем введены ли в строку латинские или кириллические символы, если же нет, то выводим сообщение об ошибке.

Также для дебага я добавил `$.validator.setDefaults` чтобы избежать отправки формы, когда протестируете что все работает верно, можете удалить этот кусок.

Так же помните что у Вашего `input` должен быть name и id, внутри `validate()` указываете какое поле должно быть провалидировано и по каким правилам, потому ставим наш новый метод `symbols: true`.

**Upd.** Добавил пример с несколькими полями. Учитывайте что `id` и `name` для каждого `input` должен быть уникальным.

```js
$.validator.addMethod("symbols", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ]+$/.test(value);
}, "You can enter symbols only");

// Только для теста, избегаем отправки формы
$.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});

$("form").validate({
   rules: {
    first_name: {
      required: true,
      symbols: true
    },
    last_name: {
      required: true,
      symbols: true
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="Имя">
  <input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text" placeholder="Фамилия">
  <input type="submit" value="Validate">
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: спасибо. но если в форме будет еще такое же поле с таким же правилом? по идее дублировать плохо

Comment: @nastya дублировать что? То что внутри `rules` есть своего рода конфигурация, какие поля и согласно каким правилам валидировать или Вы о чем?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jeg9uwc0/

Comment: @nastya `id` и `name` должны быть уникальными для каждого `input`. И немножко добавьте ясности, зачем Вы добавили ссылку на фидл.

Comment: @nastya обновил ответ, добавил два Ваших поля.

Comment: esges333 так проходит валидацию.

Comment: @nastya поправил регулярное выражение.

Comment: ввожу только символы - ошибка

Comment: @nastya подправил

Comment: спасибо огромное. Один нюанс - я могу как-то в html указать настройки? required: true,
      symbols: true ? если полей будет штук 20 таких же, то придется все в js писать

Comment: @nastya к сожалению не можете, этот плагин работает таким образом что все указывается в JS. В принципе можно было бы наверное написать JS который проходился бы по формам и их полям и собирал бы правила основываясь на data-atribut-ах но не думаю что это того стоит. Можете посмотреть видео на главной странице [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) оно +/- пояснит все принципы работы с ним.

Comment: извините.  не подскажете, по данному вопросу, пожалуйста? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1380393/Почему-не-валидирует-форму-когда-по-умолчанию-есть-value-в-инпутах