# Почему не валидирует форму, когда по умолчанию есть value в инпутах?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

если убрать **value** в инпутах  -то будет валидация и по клику на кнопку, и по изменения инпута (например, если стереть все в инпуте , то покажется ошибка)

а с **value** по умолчанию - не выводит ошибок ( после изменений в инпуте)

```js
$('form').validate();

$('input').on('input', function() {
  let form = $('form');
  form.validate();
  console.log('условие отрабатывает');
  $('#personal__form').validate();
});
```

```html
<form action="" id="personal__form">
  <input type="text" required value="Анна">
  <button>btn</button>
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

а вот тут работает,как нужно

```js
$('form').validate({
 
  });
```

```html
<form action="" id="personal__form">
  <input type="text" required >
  <button>btn</button>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял.

Comment: @Igor, есть инпут. удаляю из него Анна - не выдает ошибку, что поле пустое. А если   <input type="text" required> то будет валидация

Comment: @Igor, или все-равно не понятно?

Comment: все равно непонятно

Comment: @Igor, Форма из кабинета, использую jqueryvalidate. Суть проблемы - валидируется форма только после клика на кнопку. А при изменения инпута - нет. Убираю value - значение заполненное по умолчанию , то валидация будет работать, как нужно

Comment: Сделайте пример в вопросе, который работает так, как Вы описываете.

Comment: @Igor, добавлено

Comment: @Simon, Суть проблемы - валидируется форма только после клика на кнопку. А при изменения инпута - нет. Убираю value - значение заполненное по умолчанию , то валидация будет работать в обеих случаях ( и по клику на кнопку , и по изменения инпута)

Comment: @nastya у меня работает одинаково в обоих случаях. По изменению инпута валидация у меня отрабатывает только в том случае, если я нажал на кнопку и оно выдало ошибку и уже после этого ввожу или удаляю и вижу ошибку вновь без нажатия на кнопку.